# __host__ __device__ functions calling overloaded functions

Tags: cuda, overloading, fast-math

I do not understand whether there is function overloading in Cuda or not. I want to explain my problem on the following two functions, which I want to be able to use both on the GPU and the CPU, and I don't care about precision:

```
__host__ __device__
float myabs( float v ) {
    return abs( v + 1 ); //I want the floating point absolute value
}

__host__ __device__
float mycos( float v ) {
    return 2.f*cos( v );
}
```

1. Which function of `abs`, resp. `cos` should I call, and why?

   - `std::abs` / `abs` / `fabs` / `fabsf` / `anythingelse`
   - `std::cos` / `cos` / `cosf` / `__cosf` / `anythingelse`

(Since `__cosf` is a Cuda-intrinsic and `std::abs`/`std::cos` are not available in Cuda, I assume I have to use preprocessor directives inside my functions for those choices.)

2. Which headers should I include?
3. Does the answer to the first two questions depend on whether I compile with fast-math flags (e.g. `-ffast-math`).

If this important for the answer, I am compiling with *nvcc 10.2* under *Ubuntu 18.04.4.*, but I am rather interrested in a platform independent answer.

Comment: `__cosf` is "fast" approximated version. You can see its accuracy in the docs. The ret are a bit clear. the last `f` in the function name is to tell its a float instead of a double, otherwise the code (I think) will cast to double, compute, and cast the result to float. Not sure if the compiler will catch and fix that. A compiler replacement would make sense for `fabs`, not sure if for `cos`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Which function of abs, resp. cos should I call, and why?

If you are using floating point arguments, then conventionally you would use `fabs` and `cosf`. Those are the [standard CUDA Math API implementations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE) (and they correspond to the names of equivalent C standard library functions).

> 2. Which headers should I include?

Conventionally you should include either `math.h` or `cmath`

> 3. Does the answer to the first two questions depend on whether I compile with fast-math flags (e.g. -ffast-math).

No. Neither of those functions will be [substituted](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#intrinsic-functions) for fast intrinsics by fast math.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) In `cmath` the function `sinf ` is not declared, so how does this work then. 2) I read that nvcc with flag --fast-math translats sin to __sinf (which makes no sense for me, since sin takes doubles and __sinf takes float).

Comment: not that you asked about sinf, but it is part of cmath since c++11.

Comment: There is no compiler flag `--fast-math` for `nvcc`.  If you are referring to `--use_fast_math`, that behavior is documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#intrinsic-functions) and it has no impact on `sin`, only `sinf`.

Comment: @talonmies I looked at various sources which all differ sligthly. According to cppreference.com there is std::sinf, according to cplusplus.com there is sin, according to my header <cmath> there is std::sin, according to learn.microsoft.com there is sinf.
So what is correct/wrong resp. how should it be?